# Which to run first: do-release-upgrade or dist-upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade

I'm running a Dell Inspiron 3551
which came with Ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed.
Recently, my computer would not boot to Ubuntu,
so I had to recover Ubuntu, i.e.,
reinstall Ubuntu from scratch.

First, I ran the command `dist-upgrade` to upgrade my packages.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Given that I am starting with a clean system,
I wanted to update to Ubuntu 16.04.
I found that I can do this by running the command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

If I update to Ubuntu 16.04,
will it break some of the old 14.04 packages that I had installed?
Is it generally recommended to do `do-release-upgrade` before
running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: If you are starting with a clean system, why not just install Ubuntu 16.04 and skip this upgrade process?

Answer (score 13):

Upgrading to 16.04 also upgrades most currently installed packages to the versions they are in the 16.04 repositories thus meaning that they will work fine on 16.04 and non of them will be broken as long as you installed them all from the official repositories and not manually or from a PPA.

Running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` will upgrade all the packages to the latest version in the repositories for that specific Ubuntu version, `sudo do-release-upgrade` upgrades to new Ubuntu versions/releases.

You do not need to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before the other command because `sudo do-release-upgrade` runs the previous command first in order to make sure that all the packages on the current system are up-to-date to avoid any potential issues.

**So the answer is:** You can run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before `sudo do-release-upgrade`, but it doesn't really make any difference because `sudo do-release-upgrade` runs it to start with anyway.

Comment: What should I do? Background: I like simple instructions without "or"